# CVCaptureFromFile not working with CFileDialog

Tags: visual-c++, opencv

I have a weird problem, I cannot open asf video with  **CVCaptureFromFile** whose path is returned with **CFileDialog**.

The funny part is **CVCaptureFromFile** is not working (Returning Null)for hard-coded path after calling CFileDialog.

```
CFileDialog dlg(true);


    int Response = dlg.DoModal();

           if(Response == 1)
                  OpenFileName = dlg.GetPathName(); 

    capture = cvCreateFileCapture("c:\\123.asf");   

//returning null but working normally if I comment **dlg.DoModal();**
```

**EDIT 1:**
    its working perfectly for loading images.

Comment: place a breakpoint and check the string.

Comment: Its correct. I checked that.

Answer (score 0):

Previously I faced with a similar problem.

1. Ensure that all required codecs are installed.
2. Put `opencv_ffmpegХХХ.dll` from `opencv\bin` to the application directory (or add dll t the path)

Comment: Hi dude, I am having that dll. and i am getting path correctly.  Only thing is their combination is not working .. Anymore suggestions.???

Comment: @user2215259 Unfortunately no.